# Gerrit push to new branch does not trigger Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I have a very peculiar problem on my Jenkins. Gerrit trigger works on first master branch usually. When I create a new branch and push something to it, the build is not triggered at all. Even when I do Query and Gerrit trigger patch it does not work. But, when I open the job configuration, Save and do a manual trigger it works. The next consecutive push work as normal again.

Comment: Manual trigger= Query and trigger patch

Comment: Do you just open the job configuration and close without change anything?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira yes, just open and save.